# Outlook add in (calendar event): Recurrence is always null

Tags: events, null, calendar, outlook-web-addins, recurrence

I have an Outlook addin for calendar events, with a task pane. From the pane, I get the event data:

```
   date start: item.start.getAsync()
   date end: item.end.getAsync()
   recurrence: item.recurrence.getAsync()
```

Dates are ok, but recurrence is always null (status = 'succeeded'), although I change the recurrence in the event...

What can be the problem?

I am using to develop Outlook 365 Web

Thanks,

Diego

**EDIT:**
I receive the event when recurrence is changed:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged, handleRecurrenceChanged);
```

But in handleRecurrenceChanged() recurrence is always null...*

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding recurrence being null. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point

Comment: Thanks for you response. Then I am not doing anything wrong? I can not get the recurrence somehow? Regards, Diego

Comment: Hey Diego, we are still investigating the issue. Meanwhile, you can use the GRAPH Api to access recurrence of a meeting as a workaround: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-schedule-recurring-events

Comment: Hi, this link is for scheduling a recurrent meeting, isn't it? Can I also get the recurrence of an existing meeting with the GRAPH Api? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the code you gave me in the comment, i get the recurrence when it changes:

```
  Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged, handler, callback);
```

But only 'handler' function is called, where the recurrence is valid: console.log(JSON.stringify(eventarg.recurrence));

- Why callback function is not called?
- Why I can not get the recurrence with my function:

**`Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged, handleRecurrenceChange);`**

In this case, handleRecurrenceChange is called but when I call item.recurrence.getAsync() i get result.value = null

The same if I call item.recurrence.getAsync() when I need the recurrence (I get null)

I would like to get the recurrence when I need it (I can get all other event values properly), without saving it when changed, if possible...

Regards,

Diego

Comment: We are not able to reproduce this issue on our end. Could you please provide us a sample add-in for the same? Also, could you share a video recording of the screen while reproducing the issue?

Below is the difference between a handler and a callback for better understanding.
    1. handler -> will be called on RecurrenceChange
    2. callback -> will be called immediately after adding the handler

Documentation Link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.7&preserve-view=true#addhandlerasync-eventtype--handler--options--callback-

Comment: Could you give me an email address to send you a file? Thanks

Comment: We were not able to access your files. Outlook blocks the JS files you have uploaded.
You can try re-sending the files creating a zip file or host the files somewhere and send the URL.

Comment: I resent the email, please let me know if you can access the files. Thanks

Comment: Did you receive my files? I have modified bottom answer in this thread with simple test code. Does anyone know why I can not get current recurrence from the event? Thanks

Comment: We have received your files but the addin does not load because of unresolved references.

Comment: I have sent an email to admin@a830edad9050849405e20081103.onmicrosoft.com. Could you please check it? About the test steps I added in the response below, could you please tell me something?

Comment: We are able to repro the issue with the code shared i.e. when saveAsync API is called before the Recurrence is changed in UI.  Thanks for reporting this issue regarding Recurrence. It has been put on our backlog. We, unfortunately, have no timelines to share at this point. We will update this thread once the fix is deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could I somehow workaround this problem until it is fixed?

Comment: Testing other addins, in some cases the recurrence is properly taken from the event in this case: Open+close taskpane, change recurrence, open taskpane, get recurrence... Not in my case, so appart from the issue you repro, maybe I am doing sth wrong? Or not using an alternative way to get the recurrence?

Answer (score 0):

With my test taskpane.js I did this test:

1. Create a 'New event'
2. Change the recurrence ('daily')
3. Open the taskpane and read the recurrence in the 'Office.onReady()' method
   `g_item.recurrence.getAsync` --> Recurrence: valid value ('daily')   // OK!
4. Close the taskpane
5. Open the taskpane and read the recurrence in the 'Office.onReady()' method
   `g_item.recurrence.getAsync` --> Recurrence: valid value ('daily')   // OK!
6. Close the taskpane
7. Change the recurrence (to 'weekly')
8. Open the taskpane and read the recurrence in the 'Office.onReady()' method
   `g_item.recurrence.getAsync` --> Recurrence: previous value ('daily')    // ERROR!

*** If 'no recurrence' when taskpane 1st open, close taskpane, change recurrence (to any) and open taskpane again --> Recurrence: null

My 'onReady' method:

```
Office.onReady(info => {
     g_item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
      if (!g_item.itemId) {
         g_item.saveAsync(function (result) {
              g_item.recurrence.getAsync((asyncResult) => {
                  if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed)
                      console.log("Recurrence: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value));
              });
          });
      }
});
```

---

I add a sync handler and a button. In the 'onReady' method:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged, handler);
document.getElementById("button").onclick = onClick;
```

with the taskpane open:

1. Change recurrence from 'daily' to 'weekly' and Change event subject
   --> Recurrence handler is called TWICE:
   a) OLD recurrence value ('daily')    // ERROR?
   b) NEW value ('weekly')                   // OK!

   My handler method:

   ```
    function handler(eventarg) {
        console.log("handler. recurrence: " + JSON.stringify(eventarg.recurrence));
    }
   ```
2. Press my button. Recurrence trace has the OLD value ('daily'), but subject trace has the NEW value (like the other values from the item but the recurrence...)

   ```
    function onClick() {
       g_item.recurrence.getAsync((result) => {
           // Recurrence: previous value ('daily')   ERROR!
           if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)
              console.log("onClick. Recurrence: " + JSON.stringify(result.value));     
       });

       g_item.subject.getAsync((result) => {
          // Subject: ALWAYS printed properly when changed!!! 
          if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)
               console.log("onClick. Subject: " + JSON.stringify(result.value));
       });
    }
   ```

*** If recurrence is selected and then taskpane is open, onClick method read the value properly.