# Outlook add in (calendar event): Series ID when creating an event with recurrence

Tags: events, calendar, series, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add-in available for Calendar new events, with a task pane

When my task pane is open, in my JS code I can get the item ID:

```
  Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId
```

And if the event is part of a series, I can get the series ID:

```
  Office.context.mailbox.item.seriesId
```

My problem is I would like to know the seriesId when i am creating an event with recurrence, but it seems to be null at this moment. Only when the series is saved, and I open an item to edit (a single item from the series), I can get the series ID.

I have seen that when I open (to edit) a single item from the series, both item ID and series ID have (different) value.
But if I open the whole series (to edit) I have no series ID, since the item ID is the series ID...

So I need series ID when creating the event, to save both IDs. Then, when I open an event (to edit), I can check if it is an event of my series or my series itself...

Any help?

I am using Outlook 365 Web

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 1):

Ways to get series Id in compose mode are

1. Using `seriesId` [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-1.8#seriesid), if you are editing an event in the series.
2. Using `saveAsync` [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-1.8#saveasync-options--callback-), to save the draft series, the callback returns back the item identifier, which is the seriesId.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I see that the itemId I get with saveAsync when creating an event with recurrence becomes the series ID.

Then, when I am editing:

- **A single event** of a series, each event has a particular itemID, and all of the items of the series have the same seriesID (the initial itemID when creating the series)
- **The series**, the seriesID is null in that case, since the itemID is the original itemID (which is the seriesID).
- **An event "and the following events"** of a series, seriesID is null and the itemID is the particular one.

How can I know in the 3rd case I am editing the series I created (a part of it)? I don't know how to associate this edition with the initial seriesID I saved. I could think it is a single event edition...

Thanks,

Diego

Comment: Can you try using the recurrence apis for this? You can get the recurrence info like series details from the get recurrence. More details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-and-set-recurrence

Comment: When I use the recurrence api I get always null (Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync). I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616869/outlook-add-in-calendar-event-recurrence-is-always-null?noredirect=1#comment112571059_63616869

Comment: Can you please try out the following code (this is considering that you're trying to get the recurrence info as an organizer) - 


Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync(callback);

function callback(asyncResult){
    var context = asyncResult.context;
    var recurrence = asyncResult.value;

    if (recurrence == null) {
        console.log("Non-recurring meeting");
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(recurrence));
    }
}

Comment: I am the organizer. But that is the problem i posted in question '63616869': I am always getting recurrence=null, although I set for instance 'repeat every day' in the event... Using 'item.recurrence.getAsync' I can not get the recurrence... In the other post I read '...It has been put on our backlog', but my last comment had no response... Thanks

Comment: Hey Diego, sorry for the late response. We can reproduce this issue, and we are working on fixing it. Meanwhile, you can try to use the REST API to get the recurrence for the meeting as a workaround: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. To use the REST Api i need a valid access token, but I don't have any app registered for my Outlook addin. What (and where) should I register in order to get a token?

Comment: Hey Diego, can you still reproduce recurrence.getAsync() returning null? We have already fixed this issue on our end for OWA.

Comment: Hi, I am still getting null with item.recurrence.getAsync(). asyncResult.value is NULL although I select "Every day" in the event recurrence combo... All the other values I get with item.XXX.getAsync() are ok. I am testing on Outlook 365 web

Comment: Since this issue is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616869/outlook-add-in-calendar-event-recurrence-is-always-null, can we continue discussion there?