# Outlook addin (calendar event): Recurrence is the previous one after changed

Tags: outlook-web-addins, recurrence

I have an Outlook addin (Office 365 Web) and I need to get the event recurrence when my taskpane is open.
I am using Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync() in the 'Office.onReady' method, but the recurrence value if I change it while the taskpane is open is the previous one.

**TEST A**: Recurrence and taskpane open/close

1. Create a 'New event'
2. Change the recurrence ('daily')
3. Open the taskpane and read the recurrence in the 'Office.onReady()' method

   ```
   g_item.recurrence.getAsync --> Recurrence: valid value ('daily') // OK!
   ```
4. Close the taskpane
5. Open the taskpane and read the recurrence in the 'Office.onReady()' method

   ```
   g_item.recurrence.getAsync --> Recurrence: valid value ('daily') // OK!
   ```
6. Close the taskpane
7. Change the recurrence (to 'weekly')
8. Open the taskpane and read the recurrence in the 'Office.onReady()' method

   ```
   g_item.recurrence.getAsync --> Recurrence: previous value ('daily') // ERROR??
   ```

*** If 'no recurrence' when taskpane 1st open, close taskpane, change recurrence (to any) and open taskpane again --> Recurrence: null

My 'onReady' method:

```
Office.onReady(info => {     
    g_item = Office.context.mailbox.item;      
    if (!g_item.itemId) {         
         g_item.saveAsync(function (result) {                       
              g_item.recurrence.getAsync((asyncResult) => {                  
                    if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed)                      
                          console.log("Recurrence: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value));             
                });         
         });     
 }});
```

**TEST B:** Sync handler and button

I add a sync handler and a button. In the 'onReady' method:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged, handler);

document.getElementById("button").onclick = onClick;
```

Then, with the taskpane open:

1. Change recurrence from 'daily' to 'weekly' and Change event subject --> Recurrence handler is called TWICE:

   a) OLD recurrence value ('daily') // ERROR?

   b) NEW value ('weekly') // OK!

My handler method:

```
 function handler(eventarg) {   
    console.log("handler. recurrence: " + JSON.stringify(eventarg.recurrence));
 }
```

2. Press my button. Recurrence trace has the OLD value ('daily'), but subject trace has the NEW value (like the other values from the item but the recurrence...)

   ```
   function onClick() {    
         g_item.recurrence.getAsync((result) => {   
              // Recurrence: previous value ('daily')   ERROR!        
              if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)           
                    console.log("onClick. Recurrence: " + JSON.stringify(result.value));        
         });   
         g_item.subject.getAsync((result) => { 
                // Subject: ALWAYS printed properly when changed!!!       
                if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)           
                      console.log("onClick. Subject: " + JSON.stringify(result.value));  
         }); 
    }
   ```

*** If recurrence is selected and THEN taskpane is open, onClick method read the value properly.

Comment: In which platform(PC desktop, Mac, iOS, Office on the web) are you facing this issue?

Comment: I updated the question: I am using for development Office 365 Web

Comment: This post looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616869/outlook-add-in-calendar-event-recurrence-is-always-null . We have already responded to the original post. Let us know if there is any additional issue with which you need our help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the previous value is returned due the same error I share in 63616869 issue, isn't it? And is it correct that the Recurrence handler is called TWICE? With the old value and the new value. I do get the new value in this case, but after the old one. Or is it an error caused by the same 63616869 issue? Regards, Diego

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. We can reproduce the handler being called twice (with Old and new values). We have put that in our backlog and currently have no timelines.

Comment: This issue still persists, alongside recurrence being null in the callback when using `item.recurrence.getAsync()`. Almost a year has passed and this critical bug is not fixed.